# extra column based on aggregated results in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a table storing KLine information including security id, max/min price and date and want to calculate the gains for each security in a certain period. Here's my function

```
def get_rising_rate(start, end):
    return models.KLine.objects.\
            filter(start_time__gt=start). \
            filter(start_time__lt=end).\
            values("security__id").\
            annotate(min_price=django_models.Min("min_price_in_cent"),
                      max_price=django_models.Max("max_price_in_cent")).\
            extra(select={"gain": "max_price_in_cent/min_price_in_cent"})
            order_by("gain")
```

But I got the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1247, "Reference 'max_price' not supported (reference to group function)")
```

I can do the query with raw SQL like

```
SELECT
`security_id`,
`min_price`,
`max_price`,
`max_price`/`min_price` AS gain
FROM(
SELECT
`security_id`, 
MIN(`min_price_in_cent`) AS `min_price`, 
MAX(`max_price_in_cent`) AS `max_price`
FROM `stocks_kline` 
WHERE `start_time` > '2014-12-31 16:00:00' AND `start_time` < '2015-12-31 16:00:00'
GROUP BY `security_id`
) AS A
ORDER BY gain DESC
```

But I wonder if there's a more "django" way to get it done. I've searched "django join queryset", "django queryset as derived tables" but can't get a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this all of your code? It looks like you're referring to max_price somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
    def get_rising_rate(start, end):
        return models.KLine.objects.\
                filter(start_time__gt=start). \
                filter(start_time__lt=end).\
                values("security_id").\
                annotate(min_price=django_models.Min("min_price_in_cent"),
                          max_price=django_models.Max("max_price_in_cent")).\
                extra(select={"gain": "max(max_price_in_cent)/min(min_price_in_cent)"})
                order_by("gain")
```